# If $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ exist and are bounded on $U$, then $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $U = (-1,1)\times(-1,1) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$. Assume that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ exist at each point of $U$ and are bounded on $U$, where $(x,y)$ are the standard coordinates for $\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

Show by example that boundedness of the partial derivatives is necessary in part above; mere existence is not enough.